# When i install air slider in joomla gating no found jfolder

Tags: joomla

While installing air slider in joomla I'm getting not found jfolder error please help me.
i am using vesion 1.5.11

.Help Required

Comment: Hello, please explain further. What version of Joomla? What does he jerror message say? What problems are you having because of it?

Comment: see this thread:http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=252418